# version mismatch in mule application dependencies

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to deploy this application to the Mule server.
It works on Anypoint Studio without a problem.
When I go to deploy it on the standalone server, it fails and in the logs, I find this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible version of plugin 'APIKit' (org.mule.modules:mule-apikit-module) found. Artifact requires version '1.6.0' but context provides version '1.5.5'
```

What's weird is that the version of APIKit I used on the app is 1.6.0 which I upgraded from 1.5.5.
The app is using a domain, and the dependencies' versions between the domain and the app are the same.

What can be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you using rest-validator-extension?

Comment: How did you upgrade the dependency in Studio?

Comment: No i'm not using a rest-validator-extension. I have upgraded them uding the "manage modules" section in the project params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the domain is really using the dependency for APIKit 1.5.5. Another reason could be some incompatible version of the REST Validator Extension as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/rest-validator-extension). Also if  the domain or the application is using a jar library to import common Mule configurations it may be referring to a different version of the APIKit module. You can take a look at the logs to see what versions are being deployed.

Comment: It indeed was a version mismatch between an app that makes calls the the database and the one in which I had this problem. Thanks for your help.